# Align Partition Of HDD Using fdisk?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

I have found how to align the partition of my SSD using fdisk ([SSD article on Gentoo Wiki](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSD#fdisk)) but haven't been able to find any resources about aligning the partitions of a HDD. Is this practice necessary, or should I just let something like GPartEd align them as default? If it's something I should do to the HDD as well, where can I find a resource for the size to use for the sector and head portion of the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future Googlers, I've found this article on the Arch Linux wiki that answers this question: "[Advanced Format](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Format)". As it turns out, there are a couple tools you can use to determine the sector size on your disk (smartmontools and hdparm). See the article for more information.